# HQL inner join and date query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've been trying for hours now to get this right but I just can't find the solution.

I have a table "Orders" and a table "Events", where eventId is a foreign key in Orders. I have a list of orders which is now only filtering on event, but now I also want it to filter by date so I thought I'd change the query.

I'm trying to join the event table but I can't seem to get it to work.
This is the query:

```
    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Orders> getOrders(Integer id){
//        java.util.Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(test);
//        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        hql = "FROM Orders o join o.eventId e where o.eventId=" +id ;
        query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        return (List<Orders>) query.list();
    }
```

Comment: Your commented-out code shows how you declared a variable for the date, but I don't see anything that tells us what you tried as far as using that date in the query, or what happened when you tried it; so it's a little hard to say what went wrong.  That said, I can suggest that using query parameters is a better practice than concatenating query fragments with variables' values, and in the case of a date particularly there are less ways to make a mistake using parameters.

Comment: I commented out the date because this query was working before without trying to join with the Event table. I did this to see if I'm joining correctly..
This is working:
hql = "FROM Orders o where o.eventId=" +id ;

But this is'nt working:
hql = "FROM Orders o join o.eventId e where o.eventId=" +id ;

Comment: `join o.eventId e` looks wrong to me. It looks like you're trying to join `Orders` to a column in `Orders` rather than to another table.

Comment: When I do: hql = "FROM Orders o join Event e where o.eventId=" +id ; I get : Hibernate: Path expected for Join! exception for inner join

Comment: Maybe post your two entity classes so people can see how they're structured

Comment: I got it working. Tables are already joined in the entity classes so this query worked like: hql = "FROM Orders o where o.eventId=" +id + " and o.eventId.eventPK.date like ':sqlDate%'";

Comment: It is quite obvious that your entity mapping is wrong simply by looking at your hql. `Order` should have (ManyToOne?) relationship to `Event`, and the hql should look like `from Order o where o.event.id = :id`.  And, your whole question has nothing to do with date

Answer (score 0):

I think you must remove `join o.eventId e` because when you write:

```
where o.eventId = ...
```

HQL implicit transform your where in join condition (between Order and Event property) and where condition.

So, try this:

```
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Orders> getOrders(Integer id){
    hql = "FROM Orders o where o.eventId=" +id ;
    query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    return (List<Orders>) query.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problem in your code that can go wrong.

First, obviously you are using Hibernate wrong. You need to think in entity, not table.  And, from your HQL, it is obviously your entity mapping is wrong.

It should look like:

```
@Entity @Table(name="Orders")
class Order {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(...) @JoinColumn(name="eventId")
    private Event event;
}

@Entity @Table(name="Events")
class Order {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Temporal(...)
    private Date fooDate;
}
```

and your initial HQL should look like:

```
from Order o where o.event.id = :eventid
```

and you should pass in parameter by

```
Query query = ....;
query.setParameter("eventid", id);
```

Constructing HQL by your way can easily allow sql injection

---

if you have mapped the date field correctly, query by date is nothing difficult:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Order o where o.event.fooDate = :foodate");
q.setParameter("foodate", dateParam);
q.list();
```

---

Another problem of your code is obviously inappropriate place to put `@Transactional`